# How do I tell Jenkins what to run on my slave machine?

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins master is up and running. I have created a slave node, launched it successfully from the slave machine, and have done the web services installation so that the connection is established on startup of the slave machine. I have also created a "job" that builds successfully in Jenkins.

How do I tell Jenkins what to actually *do* on my slave machine? I want to use Jenkins to run an IntelliJ test suite (Selenium and Cucumber) on the slave machine, but haven't been able to figure out exactly how to get it to do this. Note: I've just started looking into the [Seleniumhq plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Seleniumhq+Plugin), but I'm not sure if this is what I need or not since I'm working with a remote slave.

Comment: Just curious, why did you feel the need to edit my question, @cricket_007? What value does it add, exactly?

Comment: What value does it add to complain about other's responses?

Comment: Apparently none because I guess people are going to what they're going to do on here no matter how nicely you ask

Comment: It's just more text to read, and not needed for the question you're trying to ask. That's why I removed it. If you are going to say you've searched everywhere, it's useful to mention what you've found when searching if it's related to the question

Comment: Okay. I really just wanted to know what the reason for it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My confusion here stemmed from not having my project connected to a VCS repository. Without it, I couldn't figure out how to build-out my project's workspace in the slave environment from Jenkins. I also didn't understand the concept of adding additional build steps at the time I asked this question.

Once I had the VCS connection set-up (I had to do some finagling with Git/Visual Studio Team Services to get it connected, which is why I went with "none" as my version control option at first), my workspace was built for me on the slave machine when I built the project from Jenkins. Then, I used a combination of build steps ("execute Windows batch command" and "Invoke top-level Maven targets") to carry-out the rest of the project's functions.

Answer (score 0):

Limit where the jobs can run using the 'Restrict where this project can be run' to your slave node.

[Distributed Builds in Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have this enabled on my job and have the label for the slave node connected to it in this way. So, it seems that the job is running in the correct context (of the slave node), but I still don't understand how to specify what the job is meant to do.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to create the job for the Selenium and Cucumber on the main node to get the task running. Then change the build options so it will run on the Slave node.  If you are asking how to configure the job itself, that seems like a different question, and likely needs different tags (Selenium and Cucumber) to get it addressed to the proper people.

Comment: Thanks again for the info, @Steven Scott. I provided the solution(s) I ended-up with as a separate answer for reference. I am so new to Jenkins that it was difficult to find the right terms and phrasing to convey my question, so it was more of a configuration concern which caused some confusion, as you mentioned. Our repository had Cucumber and Selenium already baked-in, so I just needed the plug-ins for Jenkins to handle that part of it.